# Brunch - Handlebars.templates is undefined

Tags: handlebars.js, brunch

I try to setup a dev environnement using brunch and handlebars. The `handlebars-brunch` package is stored in my `node_modules` and `handlebars.runtime.js` included in my `vendor.js` file. I've defined this template :

hello.template:

`<p>Hello {{name}}</p>`

And add these lines to my `config.coffee` :

```
    templates:
        defaultExtension: 'handlebars'
        joinTo: 'app.js'
```

And as a proof that it works, I can see in my `app.js` the following lines :

```
  ;var __templateData = Handlebars.template(function Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];

helpers = this.merge(helpers, Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};
var buffer = "", stack1, functionType="function", escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression;


buffer += "<p>Hello ";
if (stack1 = helpers.name) { stack1 = stack1.call(depth0, {hash:{},data:data}); }
else { stack1 = depth0.name; stack1 = typeof stack1 === functionType ? stack1.apply(depth0) : stack1; }
buffer += escapeExpression(stack1)
  + "</p>\r\n\r\n";
return buffer;
});
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define([], function() {
        return __templateData;
    });
} else if (typeof module === 'object' && module && module.exports) {
    module.exports = __templateData;
} else {
    __templateData;
}
```

But when i invoke `Handlebars.templates.hello` like this :

```
var tpl  = Handlebars.templates.hello;
var html = tpl ( { name: "ok" } );
console.log ( tpl );
```

I get this error : `Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined`. So Handlebars is defined but not templates. My dependencies inclusion seems fine too as my main function is located after everything else, like this:

```
[...]
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define([], function() {
       return __templateData;
    });
} else if (typeof module === 'object' && module && module.exports) {
    module.exports = __templateData;
} else {
    __templateData;
}

;( function ( $, document, window ) { 
    var tpl  = Handlebars.templates.hello;
    var html = tpl ( { name: "ok" } );
    console.log ( tpl );
} ( jQuery, document, window ) );
```

Any idea/suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brunch uses modules. It doesn't assign global variables or something.

```
require('name')
```

if your file was `app/name.js`

Comment: As I nest my javascript in namespaces, I have disabled the modules in config.coffee (`modules:wrapper: false definition: false`). Am I forced to use modules to use templates ? Like this : `var helloTemplate = require ('hello'); html=helloTemplate({name:'ok'})` ?

Comment: yes, like this. you need modules. there is no support for global variables in brunch plugins but if you really need them, we are open for pull requests.

Comment: Nah it's fine as long as I have a way to do it :) Thanks !